# Compiled Processing code using custom Java class drawing background but not object

Tags: java, runtime, drawing, processing

This code properly compiles and then run but my Circle object, which has a draw method containing a call to the ellipse method in Processing does not show up on the screen when it is called in the draw method. I am perplexed by this as I can change the color of the background and see that change be reflected but nothing else. First class is an abstract parent representing more complex objects to be drawn, while the Circle class only represents a 2D shape and is mainly being used for me to test out using processing in Eclipse and custom java classes. Finally there is the driver or sketch in this case, Bounce, which is supposed to put a Circle object on the screen.

```
//Name: CelestialBody

//Models generic space objects
//For ex. - Stars
//          Planets
//          Asteroids
//          Moons
//          Etc.

import processing.core.*;

public abstract class CelestialBody {
//constants
static final float c = 299792458; //speed of light in vacuum in meters per second


//object variables
String name; //name of object

float volume; //volume in cubic meters
float area; //area in square meters
float density; //density in kilograms per cubic meters
float mass; //mass in kilograms

float distanceM; //distance in meters
float distanceKM; // distance in kilometers

float xPos; //x coordinate (meters relative to origin)
float xVel; //velocity vector on x-axis in meters per second

float yPos; //y coordinate (meters relative to origin)
float yVel; //velocity vector on y-axis in meters per second

float zPos; //z coordinate (meters relative to origin)
float zVel; //velocity vector on z-axis in meters per second

PVector location= new PVector(); //location stored in vector object
PVector velocity= new PVector(); //velocity vector

PApplet parent;
//constructor
public CelestialBody(PApplet p, String name, float volume, float area, float density, float mass, 
    float x, float xVel, float y, float yVel, float z, float zVel)
    {
    parent=p;

    this.name=name;

    this.volume=volume;
    this.area=area;
    this.density=density;
    this.mass=mass;


    xPos=x;
    this.xVel=xVel;
    yPos=y;
    this.yVel=yVel;
    zPos=z;
    this.zVel=zVel;

    location.set(xPos,yPos,zVel);
    velocity.set(xVel,yVel,zVel);
}
}
```

---

```
//Name: Circle



//Models generic circle from 
//CelestialBody Class for the sake of 
// drawing practice even though this class
//is way simpler by nature and is
//not at all related to real objects

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Circle extends CelestialBody{
//object variables
float radius; //radius in meters
float diameter; //diameter in meters
PApplet parent;

//constructor
public Circle(PApplet p,String name, float mass, float x, float xVel, float y, float yVel, float radius){
    super(p,name,0,0,0,mass,x,xVel,y,yVel,0,0);
    parent=p;
    this.radius=radius;
    diameter = radius * 2;
    area=(float)(Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,2));
}

public void drawCircle() {
    //shift x and y by the radius of the circle in order to correctly center it
    parent.ellipse(location.x - radius,location.y - radius,diameter,diameter);

}
}
```

---

```
//Name: Bounce

//Draws bouncing ball in box

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Bounce extends PApplet {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "Bounce" });
  }

public void settings() {
    size(displayWidth,displayHeight);
}

public void setup(){
    background(100,150,150);
}

public void draw() {
    Circle circ = new Circle (this,"ball",150,0,10,0,10,150);
    fill(0);
    stroke(0);
    circ.drawCircle();

    circ.location.x=circ.location.x+circ.velocity.x;
    circ.location.y=circ.location.y+circ.velocity.y;

    if (circ.location.x>width||circ.location.x<0){
        circ.velocity.x=circ.velocity.x*-1;
    }
    if (circ.location.y>width||circ.location.y<0){
        circ.velocity.y=circ.velocity.y*-1;
    }   
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things going on here.

First, notice that you're always initializing a `Circle` object from your `draw()` function. You then add 10 to the x and y positions, so your `Circle` is always at location `10, 10`.

To fix that, try moving your declaration of your `circ` variable to the sketch level.

You're also drawing the circle incorrectly. Your circle always ends up to the upper-left of its actual position. Since the upper-left position of `10,10` is outside the bounds of the window, that's why you never see it.

To fix that, modify your `drawCircle()` code to draw the ellipse at the correct location. Try changing the circle's position to `mouseX, mouseY` to see what I mean.

Finally, you aren't redrawing the background every frame, so you end up with a "trail" of circles instead of a single circle. If this isn't what you want, try adding a call to `background()` inside your `draw()` function.

Comment: Thanks @KevinWorkman, I did end up adding background() to my draw() function, don't know how I over looked the loop nature of draw() and initialized the Circle in draw(). I am still confused what you mean about my drawCircle() method although from running the code I can see that the ball is not bouncing in expected manner.

Comment: using mouseX and mouseY it looks as if the circle is being drawn properly at the center, perhaps what you mean is that it is unnecessary to offset the x and y coordinates by the radius in the ellipse function.

Comment: @unprosaic I mean that the values you're using for checking for collisions are different than the values you're using to draw the ellipse.

Comment: I subtracted/added the radius to my collision checks so that the ball would bounce from its edge as opposed to its center while I was fixing the things you pointed out.